# Clickonce Publish .NET 5 app with .NET 5 runtime Prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

We recently migrated a WPF desktop application to .NET 5 and everything seems to be working fine as far as the application is concerned. This software will be installed on systems where there will no internet connection, so when we give this to our clients we need to include .NET 5 runtime as a prerequisite when they install the software. We are using VS 2019 (version 16.10) and ClickOnce publish and we selected .NET 5 desktop runtime as a prerequisite with download location as "Download from the same location as application" as below

[image]

We tried adding the .NET 5 runtime exe at various locations including the root of the application, bin folder, and also "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages". No matter where we keep the runtime exe when we do the publish it always gives this error

"To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net5desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-5.0.8-win-x64.exe' for item '.NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.8 (x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018."](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.%22)

I tried with an empty console .NET 5 app with .NET 5 runtime as perquisite and still gives the same error.

Is there a bootstrapper package for .NET 5 like we have for .NET framework 4xx at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages"?

How do we publish .NET 5 apps with .NET 5 runtime as a prerequisite using the "download" from the same location as my application" option? Please let me know if there are any other workarounds or solutions.

Comment: It has never been possible to get a framework installed with ClickOnce.  Can't work, a CO install is not allowed to make administrative changes to the machine.  The radio buttons are a bit misleading, the user merely sees a recommended download location.  Google ".net core self-contained deployment" to get ahead, not actually sure if that's possible for a WPF app.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks for pointing me in right direction, with couple of small fixes, self-contained deployment worked for us.

Comment: @Prashant Please tell me how you solved this problem?